# Unity WaitForSeconds stuck

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to create a simple splashscreen. at first this waitforseconds working, but suddenly after a few week this code doesn't want to work. I tried using debug.log but I just get the "before wait" and the "after wait" doesn't appear even after 5 minutes. I am using unity 4.5, why this is happen?

```
void Start () {
     guiTexture.pixelInset = new Rect (0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
     StartCoroutine (LoadNextScene ());
 }
 IEnumerator LoadNextScene(){
     Debug.Log ("before wait");
     yield return new WaitForSeconds (DelayTime);
     Debug.Log ("after wait");
     if (NextLevel != "") {
         Application .LoadLevel (NextLevel );    
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfect. That means one of 2 things:

1. DelayTime is excessively large (debug it out)
   or, more likely:
2. The GameObject is destroyed so the CoRoutine nolonger is running.

Try this:

```
void Start () {
     guiTexture.pixelInset = new Rect (0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
     StartCoroutine (LoadNextScene ());
 }
 IEnumerator LoadNextScene(){
     Debug.Log ("before wait. Pausing for seconds: " + DelayTime);
     yield return new WaitForSeconds (DelayTime);
     Debug.Log ("after wait");
     if (NextLevel != "") {
         Application .LoadLevel (NextLevel );    
     }
 }

void OnDestroy() {
        Debug.Log("Destroyed");
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code , I fill DelayTime with 2 seconds and I get "before wait. Pausing for seconds : 2". and then nothing happen. any idea?

Comment: And you didn't see the "Destroyed" log?

Comment: There is a 3rd alternative actually, if your code somewhere calls 'StopAllCoroutines()'

Comment: no I didn't see the Destroyed log and I don't have any code to stop all the couroutines ..

Comment: OK, so there is a 4th (and hopefully final) alternative, you must be setting Time.timeScale to 0 (which stops Time.deltaTime from increasing and stops WaitForSeconds from ever reaching your delay time).  Now, assuming you have used Time.timeScale = 0 for a valid reason then you have to recode your delay using something like Time. realtimeSinceStartup.

Comment: thank you very much .. I remember fill the timeScale with 0 when the game is over , but that scene is pretty far from this scene so I didn't think that would cause this .. problem solved when I add `Time.timeScale = 1;` inside Start() function ..

Comment: Glad we got there in the end!

Answer (score 2):

Just to consolidate answer given by @peterept, following can be reasons due to which your coroutine gets stuck on `WaitForSeconds`:

1. The time given in `WaitForSeconds` is too long. Although this is silly reason, but sometimes this happens
2. The object from which you are calling the coroutine is getting destroyed. You can check that as follow.

   ```
   void OnDestroy() {
       Debug.Log("Destroyed");
   }
   ```
3. From any place, `StopAllCoroutines()` is getting called which is stopping your coroutine.
4. Lastly, check that anywhere `Time.timeScale` is getting set to 0. Because when its zero, it stops `Time.deltaTime` from increasing and as a result `WaitForSeconds` never reaches your specified value.You can check your current timescale in `Edit -> Project settings -> Time` check Time Scale parameter in that. Or you check its value by logging before your coroutine is called.

The last one, was also faced by me and @peterept comment helped me in that.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just need to Wait for seconds. You can just use Invoke Instead of Co routine.

Until now, I still can't understand why would anyone use Co routine in a simple basis.

Co routine is usually used to let it do its own work on the background while other still run.

Ex: Checking online Data for your game. ETC. Download Assets.

That is the best way to use Co routine.

But Please, when you just want to delay some Call, just use Invoke.

```
 void Start(){
        Invoke("LoadMyScene",2);
        // LoadMyScene will be called after 2 seconds.
 }


 public void LoadMyScene(){
   Application.LoadLevel(YourLevelScenehere);

}
```

**Update**